# Isomap module cannot be executed

Tags: python

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA as sklearnPCA
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
pca_representation = pca.fit_transform(dataset_norm[index])


import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_s_curve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.manifold import Isomap as sklearnisomap
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
iso = Isomap(n_components=2, n_neighbors=40)
iso_representation = iso.fit_transform(dataset_norm[index])
```

I use google colab.
When I run the code:

iso_representation = iso.fit_transform(dataset_norm[index]),

It doesn't work, the system message says: Your session crashed after using all available RAM.

But the PCA module is working correctly, I have looked up many answers but can't solve this problem, and other codes are not working correctly, am I overlooking something?